# Deep replace a value knowing the value of an attribute within the object we must inject value in

Tags: javascript, lodash

We have a deeply nested structure which varies each time we run the app.

```
{
  some: {
    complex: {
      unknown: {
        structure: {
          fields: [
            { name: "group1", other: "data", currentValue: "" },
            { name: "group2", other: "another data", currentValue: "" },
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We must inject, in this structure, proper value. We receive for example

```
{ 
  group1: 'the proper value'
}
```

And we must replace the value in the proper group to obtain:

```
{
  some: {
    complex: {
      unknown: {
        structure: {
          fields: [
            { name: "group1", other: "data", currentValue: "the proper value" },
            { name: "group2", other: "another data", currentValue: "" },
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

We tried to use lodash mergeWith but since we cannot know where exactly is the value we must inject and we only know the value of of of the key of the object we must inject the value in, we didn't manage to get this working.

Comment: You will be injecting it into `fields` array ?

Comment: What about recursively checking the enumerable properties of the object for a matching name? You might have to refactor for disabling the enumerable flag on some other properties

Comment: Yes we must inject in the fields array. But we don't know the hierarchy where fields will be. And checking the object containing matching name, how then to reinject it at proper place to get a proper object?

Comment: You could recursively loop over each item check if it is an object until you find an array, then update the field

Comment: So to be clear you have the object and you know you must change the value beind the key `currentValue` for the group behind the key `name` : `group1`?

Comment: Having a data model that is not predictable seems like the real problem here... You will have to iterate through any object until you find the `fields` array, that's not pretty but you won't find anything better. When the data model change, can't you save a reference of that array to a stable location?

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT exactly. The only thing we can be sure is the `fields` array will be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a recursive function going through the object and mutating it depending on the value of what you seek.

```js
const obj = {
  some: {
    complex: {
      unknown: {
        structure: {
          fields: [{
              name: 'group1',
              other: 'data',
              currentValue: '',
            },
            {
              name: 'group2',
              other: 'another data',
              currentValue: '',
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

const toChange = {
  group1: 'the proper value',
  group2: 'the proper value 2',
};

// Recursive function that go replace
function lookAndReplace(config, ptr) {
  // If we deal with an object look at it's keys
  if (typeof ptr === 'object') {
    Object.keys(ptr).forEach((x) => {
      // If the keys is the one we was looking for check the value behind
      if (x === config.keyToCheck) {
        // We have found one occurence of what we wanted to replace
        // replace the value and leave
        if (ptr[x] === config.key) {
          ptr[config.keyToReplace] = config.value;
        }

        return;
      }

      // Go see into the value behind the key for our data
      lookAndReplace(config, ptr[x]);
    });
  }

  // If we are dealing with an array, look for the keys
  // inside each of the elements
  if (ptr instanceof Array) {
    ptr.forEach(x => lookAndReplace(config, x));
  }
}

// For each group we look for, go and replace
Object.keys(toChange).forEach(x => lookAndReplace({
  key: x,
  value: toChange[x],
  keyToCheck: 'name',
  keyToReplace: 'currentValue',
}, obj));

console.log(obj);
```

---

**/!\ Important this soluce also work with nested arrays**

```js
const obj = {
  some: {
    complex: {
      unknown: {
        structure: {
          // fields is an array of array
          fields: [
            [{
              name: 'group1',
              other: 'data',
              currentValue: '',
            }],
            [{
              name: 'group2',
              other: 'another data',
              currentValue: '',
            }],
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

const toChange = {
  group1: 'the proper value',
  group2: 'the proper value 2',
};

// Recursive function that go replace
function lookAndReplace(config, ptr) {
  // If we deal with an object look at it's keys
  if (typeof ptr === 'object') {
    Object.keys(ptr).forEach((x) => {
      // If the keys is the one we was looking for check the value behind
      if (x === config.keyToCheck) {
        // We have found one occurence of what we wanted to replace
        // replace the value and leave
        if (ptr[x] === config.key) {
          ptr[config.keyToReplace] = config.value;
        }

        return;
      }

      // Go see into the value behind the key for our data
      lookAndReplace(config, ptr[x]);
    });
  }

  // If we are dealing with an array, look for the keys
  // inside each of the elements
  if (ptr instanceof Array) {
    ptr.forEach(x => lookAndReplace(config, x));
  }
}

// For each group we look for, go and replace
Object.keys(toChange).forEach(x => lookAndReplace({
  key: x,
  value: toChange[x],
  keyToCheck: 'name',
  keyToReplace: 'currentValue',
}, obj));

console.log(obj);
```

---

```js
const obj = {
  some: {
    complex: {
      unknown: {
        structure: {
          fields: [{
              name: "group1",
              other: "data",
              currentValue: ""
            },
            {
              name: "group2",
              other: "another data",
              currentValue: ""
            },
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

const toChange = {
  group1: 'the proper value',
  group2: 'the proper value 2',
};

// Recursive function that go replace
function lookAndReplace({
  key,
  value,
  keyToCheck,
  keyToReplace,
}, ptr) {
  // If we deal with an object
  if (typeof ptr === 'object') {
    Object.keys(ptr).forEach((x) => {
      if (x === keyToCheck) {
        // We have found one
        if (ptr[x] === key) {
          ptr[keyToReplace] = value;
        }
      } else {
        lookAndReplace({
          key,
          value,
          keyToCheck,
          keyToReplace,
        }, ptr[x]);
      }
    });
  }

  if (ptr instanceof Array) {
    ptr.forEach(x => lookAndReplace({
      key,
      value,
      keyToCheck,
      keyToReplace,
    }, x));
  }
}

// For each group we look for, go and replace
Object.keys(toChange).forEach(x => lookAndReplace({
  key: x,
  value: toChange[x],
  keyToCheck: 'name',
  keyToReplace: 'currentValue',
}, obj));

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot and inspired us a specific case

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be to use a recursive function like this:

```js
object={
  some: {
    complex: {
      unknown: {
        structure: {
          fields: [
            { name: "group1", other: "data", currentValue: "" },
            { name: "group2", other: "another data", currentValue: "" },
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
newValue={ 
  group1: 'the proper value'
};
var inserted=false;
function search(data, newData){
    if(inserted) return;
    for(key in data){
         if(data[key]==Object.keys(newData)[0]){
              data["currentValue"]=newData[Object.keys(newData)[0]];
              inserted=true;
              return;
         }else
              search(data[key], newData);
    }
}   
search(object, newValue);
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do a recursive search and replace...

```js
let theObj = {
  some: {
    complex: {
      unknown: {
        structure: {
          fields: [
            { name: "group1", other: "data", currentValue: "" },
            { name: "group2", other: "another data", currentValue: "" },
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function updateObj(obj, replacement) {
  if(Array.isArray(obj)) {
      let key = Object.keys(replacement)[0]
      let itm = obj.find(i => i.name == key)
      itm.data = replacement[key]
  } else if(typeof obj == 'object') {
    for(let i in obj) {
      updateObj(obj[i], replacement)
    }
  }
}


updateObj(theObj, { group1: 'the proper value' })
console.log(theObj)
```

Comment: Why `key` and `itm` are `let` variables ?

Comment: Because I like `let`

Comment: So if you use this code, know that eslint will gives you [@prefer-const](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-const) errors. Because the variables are not reassign